# tightvncserver - show the same screen on hdmi and tightvncclient

Tags: vnc

I want to use tightVNCserver to display my primary screen, atm it is showing a second screen, but i want it to show my primary. how can i do that?
i want to control my raspberry pi using keyboard and mouse directly on my raspberry pi, but i want tightVNCserver to display my primary screen so i can show off what i have made.

i haven't tried anything yet, so please hook me up.

i have a raspberry pi 3 model b+ on Raspbian 9.

Comment: Use RealVNC it's a built-in component with Raspbian and all supported Raspberry Pi hardware and works a lot better than TightVNC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't.

The slightly more complex answer is that you can using `xvncserver` provided you have `X` on your computer.

Probably, in your case, the better option is to use `RealVNC`, which is included in Raspbian, and is designed to operate this way (it doesn't work if you don't have a GUI running in the Pi - although this can be changed). You need to use the RealVNC viewer on your computer.

NOTE You can only run one of tightVNCserver, RealVNC as they are mutually exclusive.